# How does tinymce store Greek text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, tinymce

i have an html page. In the page i have textarea with tinymce. So when the user writes text it is stored formatted in mysql ( with php ).
When someone writes greek text everything is working properly,
but,
when i check the text inside the database, i notice that every greek character is saved like this: &alpha, &tau, &mu....
Why is this happening?
Doesn' t it take up a lot of space in mysql to save big text in that way?
( when i use textarea without tinymce it saves greek characters normally )

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want the necessary XML entities to be encoded, and not all possible named entities as specified in the [`entities`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aentities) setting, you should probably set the [`entity_encoding`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aentity_encoding) setting to `"raw"`:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine. That line of code was totally missing from my code. I put it at the beginning. Or should put i put at the end?does it make difference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your database configuration, but I suggest you to check what charset you're are using in your database, I prefer UTF8.

Comment: Yes i have checked the database configuration but it was the entity encoding finally.